# Updating Values of a table from same table without using a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My Requirement
 Updating Values of a table from same table without using a select query
    this query won't effect any rows.
    My aim : `Update val2 of #table where slno=1 with the value of val2 of slno=2`
      Is there any other way without doing this method

```
 Declare @val2 nvarchar(50)
  select @val2=val2  from #table where slno=2
  update #table set val2=@val2 where slno=1


    create table #table 
    (
     slno int identity(1,1),
     val nvarchar(50),
     val2 nvarchar(50)
    )

    insert into #table(val,val2)values('1',newID())
    insert into #table(val,val2)values('1',newID())
    insert into #table(val,val2)values('1',newID()) 

    select * from #table 

    update #table set val2=T.val2 
      from #table T where slno=1 and T.slno=2



      drop table #table
```

I have lot of records in the table.
So If i am selecting and update it may effect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide more info.

Do you have only 2 rows in your table?

Why do you need this kind of update?

I suppose, that your db structure is wrong, but I can't tell exactly, until you explain why do you need this.

Anyway I can suggest a poor way to do this without using select. You can self join the table. It would be better to have addition column, but if you don't have it, how's you should do

```
    UPDATE T1
    SET T1.val2 = T2.val2
    FROM #table T1 INNER JOIN #table T2 
       ON T1.slno = 1 AND T2.slno = 2
```